# Ruby regex: parsing git commit messages for youtrack issue codes

Tags: ruby, regex, git, youtrack

I'd like to parse and remove youtrack issue codes embedded anywhere in commit messages.

For those who have never used youtrack, you can specify issue codes in commits as follows:

```
#<project>-<issue#> <commit msg> 
e.g. #PROJ-3 I like to use git and youtrack
```

or...

```
e.g. I'm silly #PROJ-3 and like to use git and youtrack
```

I have the following regex...

```
$remove_issue_regex = /( |^)#(\w+-\d+):? ? -? ?/
```

...which I feed into a sub method replacing the substring with an empty string. But it's ugly and might not work if the user formats their messages in a silly way. Does anyone know a more elegant way to do this?

Comment: so you want to remove `I like to use git and youtrack` from the above message. Am i correct?

Comment: Yes, but the issue code could be anywhere in the message.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a lookbehind,

```
(?<= |^)#(\w+-\d+)(?=: - )?
```

[Rubular](http://www.rubular.com/r/6BDfh1zhN8)

OR

```
(?<= |^)#(\w+-\d+)(?:: - )?
```

[Rubular](http://www.rubular.com/r/N17rqk4YvQ)

Just replace the whole string with the first captured group to get only the `<project>-<issue>` format.

Comment: This will work when combined with String::squeeze to get rid of any leftover spaces. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

`$remove_issue_regex = /#\w+-\d+ (.*)/`

will put the commit message after the stamp as the first capture group